# Generate AES key from RSA encoded AES key

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes, rsa

What I am trying to do is to encrypt a string with AES, encrypt the AES key getEncoded() value with RSA, then decrypt that AES getEncoded() value so that I get my original string. The public key is loaded from the users certificate, and the private key from file.
The code is given below.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
String myString = "My Message";
    KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    keyGenerator.init(128);

    SecretKey secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();

    byte[] initializationVector = new byte[128 / 8];//16
    SecureRandom prng = new SecureRandom();
    prng.nextBytes(initializationVector);

    Cipher AESCipherForEncryption = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");

    AESCipherForEncryption.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(initializationVector));

    byte[] byteVersionOfMyMessage = myString.getBytes();
    byte[] byteVersionOfCipherText = AESCipherForEncryption.doFinal(byteVersionOfMyMessage);
    String cipherText = new BASE64Encoder().encode(byteVersionOfCipherText);

    InputStream in1 = new FileInputStream("user.crt");
    CertificateFactory cf1 = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");
    Certificate c1 = cf1.generateCertificate(in1);
    X509Certificate toSendcert = (X509Certificate) c1;
    PublicKey publicKey = toSendcert.getPublicKey();
    String cipherTextRSA = encryptRSA(publicKey, new String(secretKey.getEncoded()));

    String decypheredRSA = decryptRSA(getPrivateKey("user.pk8", "RSA"), cipherTextRSA);
    System.out.println(cipherTextRSA);
    System.out.println(decypheredRSA);

    SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(new String(decypheredRSA.getBytes("UTF-8")).getBytes(), 0, new String(decypheredRSA.getBytes("UTF-8")).getBytes().length, "AES");

    Cipher AESCipherForDecryption = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
    AESCipherForDecryption.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, originalKey, new IvParameterSpec(initializationVector));
    byte[] byteVersionOfDecriptedText = AESCipherForDecryption.doFinal(new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(cipherText));
    String decMessage = new String(byteVersionOfDecriptedText);
    System.out.println(decMessage);
}
public static String encryptRSA(PublicKey pubKey, String message) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
    Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
    String encryptedString = encoder.encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    return encryptedString;
}

public static PrivateKey getPrivateKey(String filename, String algorithm) throws Exception {
    File f = new File(filename);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[(int) f.length()];
    dis.readFully(keyBytes);
    dis.close();

    String temp = new String(keyBytes);
    String privKeyPEM = temp.replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
    privKeyPEM = privKeyPEM.replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
    privKeyPEM = privKeyPEM.replace("\n", "");

    byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(privKeyPEM);

    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(decoded);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
    return kf.generatePrivate(spec);
}

public static String decryptRSA(PrivateKey prKey, String encrypted) throws Exception {
    Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
    byte[] input = decoder.decode(encrypted);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, prKey);

    return new String(cipher.doFinal(input));
}
```

The error that I keep getting is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid AES key length: 28 bytes
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineGetKeySize(AESCipher.java:509)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.passCryptoPermCheck(Cipher.java:1067)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.checkCryptoPerm(Cipher.java:1038)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.implInit(Cipher.java:805)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:864)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1396)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1327)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:79)
```

If I don't encrypt and decrypt the `secretKey.getEncoded()` value, and just use AES without RSA it works properly. Also working with RSA, if I just encrypt some string with a public key, and decrypt it with a private it works. My question would be: "How could I properly encrypt and decrypt the `secretKey.getEncoded()` value with RSA, so that I can properly encrypt and decrypt `myString`?".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encrypting AES key with RSA public key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658921/encrypting-aes-key-with-rsa-public-key)

Comment: @vinS it is not a duplicate, since the answer to that question was to use padding, which I have used but to no avail

Answer (score 1):

```
new String(secretKey.getEncoded())
```

This won't work as AES keys contain random bytes, and not every byte is a character representative. The problem with the standard string conversion in Java is that it drops unknown characters and bytes instead of generating an exception during encoding / decoding.

RSA operates on bytes, you should not turn the key into string and then back again into bytes as the transformation may be lossy (e.g. dropping 4 of the 32 bytes).

Alternatively - and probably even better - you may want to try the wrapping modes of cipher instead. This should be compatible with some hardware solutions out there. In that case you don't even have to call `getEncoded`.

---

OAEP encryption and authenticated encryption modes such as GCM should be preferred over PKCS#1 padding (the default for the Sun providers) and CBC mode encryption.

Comment: Never ever use `new String` or `getBytes` without indicating a character set (from `StandardCharsets`).

Comment: Unless you need to communicate with other platform specific code that doesn't explicitly define a charset, of course.