# How to encrypt a txt file after obtaining a public key shared between a client/server in Java

Tags: java, encryption, diffie-hellman

I finally figured out how to perform a Diffie-Hellman key exchange in Java, the problem now is that I have to encrypt a txt file using the shared key. I do not know how to even start to do that. The txt file is just simply  the integers 1 2 3 4 5 each on a new line. Is there a simple line of code I do not know about that can perform this function? The shared key that I have is 18.0.

Comment: `Is there a simple line of code` - no. Encryption is not simple and should not be rolled on your own. Can you elaborate further which kinds of keys you are exchanging and what the use case is? I strongly recommend using well-tested libraries when doing encryption. Implementing key exchanges or the encryption itself on your own often leads to big security flaws.

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658921/encrypting-aes-key-with-rsa-public-key

Comment: Is it some learning project? Or do you plan to really use it? What do you really want to achieve? When it's a secure transmission of data (data file), why don't you use normal TLS/SSL? (resp. with client authentication)?

Comment: This is for a school project. I just have to create a socket connection between a client and server which I did. Then I have to do a Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange and then use the public key to encrypt a txt file on the server side then send the encrypted file to the client. Then I have to decrypt the file on the client side. The server should also send the hash of the encrypted file and the client should verify that it received the same file by hash comparison.

Answer (score -1):

> encrypt a txt file after obtaining a public key shared between a client/server in Java

Let's assume you are working on a learning or toy project, otherwise there's no point of (re)inventing your own secure communication. If you want to take the security seriously, just use TLS/SSL (optionally with 2-way client auth ssl) for online content transmission.

I really hope for your own sake you are just learning or playing with this.

> to encrypt a txt file using the shared key. I do not know how to even start to do that.

For encryption in rest (encrypting the file itself) - assuming from the question that the sender and receiver are having their own keypairs.

I suggest to create a random data encryption key to encrypt the content. Then you could simply use receiver's public key to encrypt the data encryption key and sign the content's hash using sender's private key. Never use plain (textbook) RSA, use propper padding.

I made a few notes [about encryption](https://gusto77.wordpress.com/2017/10/30/encryption-reference-project/) for myself, you can take some inspiration.

> The shared key that I have is 18.0.

Apprently you are using not long enough or not random enough public keys. Symmetric ciphers require keys of fixed length (e.g. AES requires 128, 192 or 256 bit keys). You could generate longer keys using any key derivation function or hash. If you want to use two-way communication, you need a separate key for each direction.

Regardless that - short key seed (small shared key, short public keys) would be feasible for brute-forcing. There are many ways how you could shoot yourself in your leg when dealing with crypto, so use some industrial standard when possible (e.g. TLS).